# Replace patterns separated by delimiter in R

Tags: r

I need to remove values matching `"CBII_*_*_"` with `"MAP_"` in vector `tt` below.

`tt <- c("CBII_27_1018_62770", "CBII_2733_101448_6272", "MAP_1222")`

I tried

`gsub("CBII_*_*", "MAP_")` which won't give the expected result. What would be the solution for this so I get:

`"MAP_62770", "MAP_6272", "MAP_1222"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
gsub("^CBII_.*_.*_", "MAP_",tt)
```

or

```
stringr::str_replace(tt, "^CBII_.*_.*_", "MAP_")
```

**Output**

```
[1] "MAP_62770" "MAP_6272"  "MAP_1222"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `trimws` from `base R` along with `paste`.  We specify the `whitespace` as characters (`.*`) till the `_`.  Thus, it removes the substring till the last `_` and then with `paste` concatenate a new string ("MAP_")

```
paste0("MAP_", trimws(tt, whitespace = ".*_"))
#[1] "MAP_62770" "MAP_6272"  "MAP_1222"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub(".*(?<=_)(\\d+)$", "MAP_\\1", tt, perl = T)
[1] "MAP_62770" "MAP_6272"  "MAP_1222"
```

Here we use positive lookbehind to assert that there is an underscore `_` on the left of the capturing group `(\\d+)` at the very end of the string (`$`); we recall that capturing group with `\\1` in the replacement argument to `sub` and move `MAP_`in front of it.